# Cocoa PDFView does not resize

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdfview

I am attempting to create a custom subclass of the `PDFView` class in XCode. I add a `PDFView` instance to my window in InterfaceBuiler and create the following files for the subclass:

**MyPDFView.h:**

```
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@interface MyPDFView : PDFView

-(void)awakeFromNib;
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;

@end
```

**MyPDFView.m:**

```
#import "MyPDFView.h"

@implementation MyPDFView

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setAutoresizingMask: NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewMinXMargin|NSViewMaxXMargin|NSViewMinYMargin|NSViewMaxYMargin];
    [self setAutoScales:YES];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    unsigned long mask = [self autoresizingMask];
    NSLog(@"self autoresizingMask: %lu",mask);
    NSLog(@"NSViewHeightSizable: %lu",mask & NSViewHeightSizable);
    NSLog(@"NSViewWidthSizable: %lu",mask & NSViewWidthSizable);
    NSLog(@"self setAutoScales: %@",[self autoScales] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSView* sv = [self superview];
    NSLog(@"superview autoresizesSubviews: %@",[sv autoresizesSubviews] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSSize frame_dims = [self frame].size;
    NSLog(@"Frame: (%f,%f)",frame_dims.width,frame_dims.height);
    NSSize bounds_dims = [self bounds].size;
    NSLog(@"Bounds: (%f,%f)",bounds_dims.width,bounds_dims.height);
    NSSize sv_frame_dims = [sv frame].size;
    NSLog(@"Superview Frame: (%f,%f)",sv_frame_dims.width,sv_frame_dims.height);
    NSSize sv_bounds_dims = [sv bounds].size;
    NSLog(@"Superview Bounds: (%f,%f)",sv_bounds_dims.width,sv_bounds_dims.height);
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}
@end
```

However, despite setting everything appropriately and the subsequent `NSLog` statements that trigger when the `PDFView` area is clicked confirming that the object SHOULD be resizing, resizing the window does not resize the `PDFView`. Can anyone explain what I need to do to make the `PDFView` area scale with the size of the parent window?

The full code for this project that will allow you to build and run it is here:

https://github.com/samuelmanzer/MyPDFViewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your requirement is to resize the `PDFView` as you resize the parent window. There are two ways of achieving this

1. Setting The Autoresizing Mask

   - Even though you have programatically set the Autoresizing mask, this isn’t effective as autolayout has been turned on for your views (When you create projects by default on Xcode 5, the xib files are by default set for autolayout
     ). Turn off the Autolayout feature by unchecking the “Use Autolayout” checkbox in the "Identity and Type" tab in the Utilities pane in Xcode for the MainMenu.xib file.
   - Modify the MyPDFView's **-(void)awakeFromNib** by adding the line of code`[self setFrame:[self superview].bounds];`
2. Using Autolayout by defining layout constraints

   - This can be done in the Interface Builder or through code programatically. [Please do read Apple Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was unaware of how autolayout overrides the programmatic options. One note: it is in the 'File Inspector' tab rather than the 'Identity Inspector' tab in Xcode 5.