# Cocoa Views do not Resize when Parent Window Resized

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have tried to convert different view objects to make them resizable by calling the following code within my derived class:

```
[self setAutoresizingMask: NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewMinXMargin|NSViewMaxXMargin|NSViewMinYMargin|NSViewMaxYMargin ];
NSView* sv = [self superview];
[sv setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

However, this hasn't worked for the views that I have tried (NSImageView and PDFView). They do not resize when the parent window is resized. Is there something else that I need to call?

Comment: why are you doing this in code at all? use IB and autolayout.

Comment: I haven't been able to locate an option in IB that got PDFView to resize correctly, so I tried to do it in code. I'll certainly accept an answer that describes how to do it in IB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out whether the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20078702/2102948) posted for [question]:[Cocoa PDFView does not resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037327/cocoa-pdfview-does-not-resize/20078702#20078702)
solved your problem.